# Vue2 - Using :checked on checkbox input breaks default behaviour

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm doing a "status update" component of sorts, in my actual component I'm marking the first custom checkbox (the circles at top, etc.) as `checked`...but for the CodePen below, I just marked them all as `:checked='false'` to iterate my issue.

The "twitter" checkboxes won't check and uncheck. The Facebook ones will.

I'm certain this has to do with the fact that I'm enabling/disabling a character counter on the twitter checkboxes. If you click one of the twitter checkboxes, you'll notice the character counter turn on, but the checkbox is never checked (or rather, is checked then immediately unchecked)...

For example, in the method `toggleMaxCharLength()`, if I comment out `self.enableMaxCharLength = true;`, the checkbox work as they should.

If I remove the `:checked='false'` from the input `v-for`, works as it should...

**UPDATE - WORKING PEN AND SOLUTION:**
https://codepen.io/mikebarwick/pen/qXdqBO

Comment: I did not downvote but can you paste your relevant code in the question in case the codepen link does. This will allow this question to be helpful to future readers

Comment: Did you look at the CodePen? It's a lot of code - why flood the question, which is sure to overwhelm users from reading and/or providing an answer. I explained a use-case and provided a link to the relative code.

Comment: @MikeBarwick I converted the pen into a snippet in my answer just as an example. The main concern with links is that links break.

Comment: Thanks, yeah. I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the twitter accounts causes a re-render, which, of course, sets your `checked` value to false.

You need to remember the checked value. I made a couple small modifications that will do so, but there are other ways.

```
<input type="checkbox"
       :ref="key"
       :name="scheduleUsingBuffer ? 'buffer_profiles[]' : key + '[]'" 
       :value="scheduleUsingBuffer ? account.profile_id : account.page_id"                              
       :checked="account.checked"   
       @change="handleAccountInputChange(key, account)">
```

And

```
handleAccountInputChange(type, account) {
  this.$set(account, 'checked', !account.checked)
  if (type == 'twitter') {                  
    this.toggleMaxCharLength();
  }
},
```

[Updated pen](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/rzVjKG?editors=1010).

Another way to avoid this would be to abstract the checkboxes into their own components that remember their state so that when the parent re-renders, the state of the checkboxes is not overwritten.

Also, the pen converted into an SO snippet.

```js
var accounts = {
  facebook: {
    testing1: {
      page_id: '23derf56hg',
      img_url: null
    }
  },
  twitter: {
    testing2: {
      page_id: 'fr2wlfrhoi',
      img_url: null
    },
    testing3: {
      page_id: '92frgl5639',
      img_url: null
    }
  }
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      Object.keys(accounts).forEach((site, siteIndex) => {
        Object.keys(accounts[site]).forEach((account, actIndex) =>{
          accounts[site][account]["checked"] = (siteIndex === 0 && actIndex === 0)
        })
      })
      console.log(accounts)
      this.connectedAccounts = accounts
    }, 100)
  },
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    connectedAccounts: [],
    scheduleUsingBuffer: false,
    formData: {},
    enableMaxCharLength: false,
    maxCharCount: 140,
    remainingCharCount: 140,
    isAboveMaxCharCount: false,
    statusMessage: ''
  },
  
  methods: {
    onSubmit(event) {
    this.formData = serialize(event.target, { hash: true });
  },
    
    toggleMaxCharLength() {
   this.enableMaxCharLength = false;

   Vue.nextTick(() => {
    var self = this;

    this.$refs.twitter.forEach(twitterInput => {
        if (twitterInput.checked) {
         self.enableMaxCharLength = true;
        }
    });
   });  
    },
    
    handleAccountInputChange(type, account) {
      this.$set(account, 'checked', !account.checked)
   if (type == 'twitter') {     
    this.toggleMaxCharLength();
   }
  },

  countdown() {
    this.remainingCharCount = this.maxCharCount - this.statusMessage.length;
    this.isAboveMaxCharCount = this.remainingCharCount < 0;
  }    
  }
})
```

```css
section.create-story {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 425px;
}
section.create-story h4 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
}
section.create-story .switch {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
section.create-story #connected-accounts {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
section.create-story #connected-accounts label.account-checkbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
section.create-story #connected-accounts label.account-checkbox .avatar {
  position: relative;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center !important;
  background-color: #CCC !important;
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
section.create-story #connected-accounts label.account-checkbox .avatar,
section.create-story #connected-accounts label.account-checkbox .account-icon {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  opacity: 0.3;
}
section.create-story #connected-accounts label.account-checkbox .avatar:hover,
section.create-story #connected-accounts label.account-checkbox .account-icon:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
section.create-story #connected-accounts label.account-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
section.create-story #connected-accounts label.account-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .avatar {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
section.create-story #connected-accounts label.account-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .avatar + .account-icon {
  color: green;
}
section.create-story #connected-accounts label.account-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .avatar, section.create-story #connected-accounts label.account-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .avatar + .account-icon {
  filter: grayscale(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
section.create-story #connected-accounts label.account-checkbox .account-icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  right: -4px;
  bottom: -4px;
  background: white;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0px rgba(49, 49, 93, 0.05), 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(49, 49, 93, 0.2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
section.create-story #status {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
}
section.create-story #status textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 14px;
  min-height: 60px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
section.create-story #status .remaining-chars.has-text-danger {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <section class="create-story box content">
   <h4>New Story</h4>

  <form id="new-story" v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <div id="status">
     <div id="connected-accounts">
       <span v-for="(accounts, key, index) in connectedAccounts">
        <label v-for="(account, i) in accounts" class="account-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox"
                         :key="key"
                    :ref="key"
                    :name="scheduleUsingBuffer ? 'buffer_profiles[]' : key + '[]'" 
                    :value="scheduleUsingBuffer ? account.profile_id : account.page_id"                    
                    :checked="account.checked"  
                    @change="handleAccountInputChange(key, account)"> <!-- mark first account as "checked" :checked="index == 0 && i == 0" -->
                  
                    <div 
                      class="avatar"
                      :style="'background: url(' + account.img_url + ')'">
                    </div>

                      <i :class="'account-icon fa fa-' + key"></i>
                  </label>
              </span>     
      </div>

    <div class="control">
       <textarea @keyup="countdown" v-model="statusMessage" name="status-message" class="textarea" placeholder="What story do you have to tell?"></textarea>
      </div> 

    <div class="level">
       <div class="level-right">
        <div v-if="enableMaxCharLength" class="level-item">
         <span :class="{'has-text-danger': isAboveMaxCharCount}" class="remaining-chars" v-text="remainingCharCount"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="level-item">
         <input type="submit" value="Schedule" class="button  is-primary"> 
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Going to try this out when back from lunch. At first glance though, `:checked="account.checked"`, the json will not (and won't have) a `checked` key/value. In my actual code, I'm setting the `:checked` value to truthy only on the first item (i.e :checked="index == 0 && i == 0")

Comment: @MikeBarwick I compensated for that in the `handleAccountInputChange` method. If the value isn't there, it will add it. Have a good lunch!

Comment: Indeed, but I don't think that's going to work. `:checked="account.checked"` is going to be `:checked="index == 0 && i == 0"`, causing the `$set` to not function as planned. Right?

Comment: @MikeBarwick I see your point. Is it *only* ever the first value? Is it really the case that you want to *default* to the first value being checked?

Comment: That's correct, first checkbox should always be `checked`. Maybe there's a better approach to this... Note: `index == 0 && i == 0` won't work with fake codepen data.

Comment: @MikeBarwick *Generally* with Vue you want the UI to reflect data, so the better approach would probably be to add `checked` prior to rendering. If the data comes from a service, that would be in the success callback where you would set checked for each account and the first one would be true.

Comment: @MikeBarwick I added to the snippet a mounted() handler that simulates adding the checked property to the data.

Comment: Awesome, thanks dude. You've pointed me in the right direction, and gave me various routes. Thanks again!

Comment: Fine tuned your `mounted()` method. Removed it from mounted, create a new method for it and ran that function after Ajax request (to get accounts, etc). Works like a charm now - and I learned something along the way!

Comment: @MikeBarwick sounds great!

Comment: I also used `Vue.nextTick` versus the `setTimeout`, which sends my OCD flying through the roof lol. Updating my original question codepen to include working code.